# Where is the apk for my new build variant?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I read the "Build System" section of the android docs: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

So a build variant is composed of a product_flavor-build_type.  I have this build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled !skipProguard
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        zipAlignEnabled false
    }
    debugtest {
        // unit tests
        applicationIdSuffix '.test'
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        zipAlignEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

productFlavors {
    internal {
        applicationId "${project.applicationId}.internal"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'EXPERIMENTAL', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FAKE_HTTP_RESPONSE', 'false'
    }
    production {
        applicationId project.applicationId
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'EXPERIMENTAL', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FAKE_HTTP_RESPONSE', 'false'
    }
    automation {
        applicationId "${project.applicationId}.automation"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'EXPERIMENTAL', 'true'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FAKE_HTTP_RESPONSE', 'true'
    }
}
```

I'd like to create mobile-debug-automation-unaligned.apk so that I can use the "FAKE_HTTP_RESPONSE" BuildConfig variable in a dagger module.

But when I click on "Build Variants" in Android Studio I see one build variant-"internalDebug".  I expected to see 9 build variants(buildType * productFlavor).

Looking in my project directories, I see the following apks:

MY_APP/mobile: mobile-release.apk, mobile-debug-unaligned.apk

MY_APP/mobile/build/outputs/apk: mobile-internal-debug-unaligned.apk

How do I generate my new "automation" apk?

Comment: You should be able to see all 9 Build variants in Build Variants window. You can pick one and then from menu build or run app and it will generate its apk. If you don't see all Build variants then you have to check if your productFlavors folders have correct names.

Comment: Try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz click on it to change:

[image]

If it doesn't work, rebuild your project.